# Blacklist the [microsoft] and [apple] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

As [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190916/146482) already sufficiently elaborated upon, there is absolutely *no* sensible reason for the tags [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) (together ~7k questions) to exist. Naming the concrete product involved is the appropriate tagging here, therefore I propose eliminating these tags for good.

Comment: Well, we probably shouldn't just remove them from all questions that currently have them, as those questions might not have sufficient other tags and might get lost, so someone will need to go through them manually, so this should probably be a burnination request first.

Comment: @Dukeling I don't know, maybe we could check for non-closed questions that don't have any other tags, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were only few. And if the question itself can't clarify on why it is MS/Apple-related (thus providing enough information to add a useful tag) the question should be closed as "unclear what you're asking" anyway

Comment: @TobiasKienzler It's not really / necessarily about **any** other tags, it's more about **some** other not-so-useful or incorrect tags. Too many questions are badly tagged, we can't just go closing all of them even if they're good questions otherwise.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm not sure I can follow you there - how does closing relate to the suggested blacklisting? If you're referring to my previous comment, I can't see how an additional tag [tag:microsoft] or [tag:apple] can fix ill-posed questions. And if they _are_ well phrased, stripping those tags won't break anything

Comment: @TobiasKienzler You mentioned closing... If they have tags like [tag:microsoft] or [tag:apple], there's a decent chance that they aren't properly tagged. There's a fair chance that they are ill-posed as well, but not necessarily, and even if they are, it doesn't mean that, underneath all that, there isn't a really awesome question. So, for these reasons, the questions with those tags needs to be reviewed.

Comment: And then there's the ambiguity - say there's an Apple product called Pi, and there's an [apple-pi] tag, if a question is tagged [apple][pi] ([pi] meaning the constant 3.14... obviously), we need to change that to [apple-pi] not just remove [apple] and risk losing what the question is about (many questions exclusively mention languages / tools / products via tags - it's not elsewhere in the question at all, and the tags should be sufficiently meaningful). (I don't know if there exists such a case, so I see it as a bit of a risk).

Comment: @Dukeling That second argument makes sense, though in that case the questions would be a) is there a [tag:pie] tag that has an entirely different meaning (is there e.g. any [tag:excel] but the [tag:microsoft] one?) and b) _should_ the tag be [tag:apple-pie] instead of [tag:pie] (since everyone knows what belongs on a proper pie)?

Comment: Please do note that we haven't been able to get a tag blacklisted in well more than a year.

Comment: @Charles It's been a slow year then ;)

Comment: Is there no way to blacklist tags moving forward?  Why do we have to retag old questions?

Comment: Hm. Why does it still reference those tags on MSE?

Comment: @Deduplicator looks like  a bug, you can report it on MSE. (though it might be caching, so give it a day before reporting)

Comment: @Deduplicator I made a dummy-edit to fix it, though the same applies to the answers - I won't edit them though, so you can report a bug if it doesn't change...

Comment: Might as well blacklist PayPal too while we're at it.

Answer (score 37):

In general, I would recommend to black-list all the non-programming tags. As Non-Programming questions are off-topic for SO, ie, [yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo) [hotmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter)[orkut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orkut)[myspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/myspace) [blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackberry)[nokia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nokia)  etc.

For these more specific tags should be included to post. So it is easy to filter out.

[Here is more detailed answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190916/183757).

> Things like "Microsoft" and "Apple" are users tagging things incorrectly. The company name is meant to be a *part* of the tag, like "Microsoft Power Point" would be [microsoft-powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint), but users type it with a space as "microsoft powerpoint" and it suddenly becomes two tags [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint). The brand is part of the product name. Though we oftentimes just crop off the brand name because it makes the tag longer and it's not really useful.
>
> The [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) tags are not useful at all. Microsoft and Apple both have a zillion different products under them, which makes these tags extremely ambiguous at best.
>
> These tags should both be burned to death.

Comment: [tag:facebook], [tag:twitter], [tag:myspace]... is fine. It is about the specific product. (if you ask a question tagged [tag:twitter], I assume that it involves the twitter API). [tag:microsoft] and [tag:apple] are both vendors with a lot of products, so it is not clear about WHAT product this question is, so we need an other tag, which make them both useless. For [tag:nokia] - I don't know enough.

Comment: twitter is a vendor... [Here is list of libraries twitter is maintaining. so its can not twitter-api when u say twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries)

Comment: Another good example is of a Twitter tag is "twitter-bootstrap".

Comment: The `microsoft` tag has just reappeared. I untagged the 3 questions that were tagged with it seems I'm not trusted to (vote to) delete the tag itself.

Comment: As a reminder to new users who haven't reached the "edit without approval" threshold -- please DO NOT make edit suggestions purely to remove these tags - it requires many more people's effort to then APPROVE those edits.

Answer (score -16):

Some questions might be about the company themselves, which is when that tag would be appropriate.  If you look at their tag wikis, they are about the corporations, and specifically state to be careful using them.

Comment: I can't think about a valid reason why a question about Microsoft/Apple is appropiate. Maybe you have an example?

Comment: asking about corporation is off-topic.

Comment: I'll try to come up with an example, but there are certainly plenty of historical questions that those tags could be applied to correctly.  ___"There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,
Than are dreamt of in your philosophy."___

Comment: Here's one that's ok: http://stackoverflow.com/q/926500/13295

Comment: I opine that the tag should be [tag:microsoft-mvp] or similar.

Comment: Yeh, that's probably a good call.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix that, since [tag:mvp] is _definitely_ the wrong tag there (also @Colin'tHart)