# Followup to "Blacklist the [microsoft] and [apple] tags"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

This is a followup to [Blacklist the [microsoft] and [apple] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags).  The request was asked back in 2013 and not only does [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) still exist but they are still getting questions using them.  The info for both of these tags says to not use them but people are still posting to them.  Is there any plan to blacklist and or burn these tags?

Comment: There's over 7,000 questions in each of those tags combined.  As much as I'd like to see them gone myself, it'd be difficult to accomplish without moderator intervention.  To be blunt, I'd much rather see that silly "DO NOT USE" notification removed since it's *not accomplishing jack*.

Comment: @Makoto: You mean nearly 7000 in both together. Anyway, is there now a way for moderators to lock a tag, or is that still a distant dream? Because I think that would be just about neccessary for successful cleanup.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I think it is possible to blacklist a tag that is still in use, but unrelated edits to the posts start to fail because the new version of the question fails the "no blacklisted tags" check.

Comment: Makoto @Deduplicator blacklisting needs developer action. Moderators can't do anything. Maybe you will have some luck poking a random *cough*animuson*cough* CM,

Comment: @BenVoigt Is unrelated edits failing a big problem? If people are editing it anyway, they could just remove the tag.

Comment: It would be nice if we could at least get this tag blacklisted so the problem doesn't keep growing.  I don't see the problem with forcing an editor to get rid of a bad flag while they are in the post editing it anyways.

Comment: @rjmunro: I'm just repeating the reason the diamond mods give for not blacklisting tags that are still attached to questions.  I personally wouldn't expect it to be a big issue either.

Comment: Just a reminder to people who might be reading this and considering taking action: please do **not** attempt to unilaterally manually remove this tag from all these questions, **doubly** so if you don't have full editing privileges. The discussion on how to handle this is ongoing, and no bulk tag editing should be done by someone whose edits have to go through the review queue - that isn't a good use of reviewer manpower. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate for more info.

Comment: @NathanOliver: hey we're down to 2411 from 7000 :)

Comment: @OurManInBananas The 7000 was a combined total.  the combined total as of right now is 6197.

Comment: @NathanOliver: well, at least we've killed a lot of the *Microsoft* ones, plus improved a few questions, flagged a few, I even found a couple of gems and put bounties on them ...

Answer (score 23):

If I edit all 7000 of those questions and change all the [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) tagged questions to proper tags like [microsoft-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-azure) or [microsoft-powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint) or [microsoft-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) and all the [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) to things like [apple-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-ios) etc will I get a gold badge?

But seriously, while it certainly makes sense to remove these tags, it has been mentioned before, there's a chance that some questions will get lost or lose visibility...

Is there a process open to the moderators or programmers to run a script to combine the tags in all questions that have both Microsoft and (say) excel into [microsoft-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)? A quick check, and there are [195 questions tagged with microsoft AND excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft+excel)

This could be a script but would have to include all the possible products and permutations...

Right, I'm off to make a start, I figure if I do 10 per day, by 2020 we should be able to lock those tags!

Comment: If 700 of us each do 10 edits, we'd have it done in no time, and we could fix / edit / close those questions along the way  :-)

Comment: @JonasCz: It's Saturday evening and I'm editing posts on SO - how sad is that lol :)

Comment: I think your calculation doesn't take into account the amount of tags added daily which are tagged with those meta tags.  I think your estimate is optimistic but off by two years. ;)

Comment: One nitpick: in your example, I'd just remove the [tag:microsoft] tag from questions with [tag:microsoft]+[tag:excel]. No reason to create a second Excel tag.

Comment: @alexwlchan: yes you're right...

Comment: @Makoto: we're down to 2411 - I guess there's quite a few of us working on this project...

Comment: @OurManInBananas Yes, quite a few but you are all making trivial edits that are bumping these posts to the main page.

Comment: What should we do when reviewing these edits ? They are trivial edits that add little or no value to a questions. I have been skipping them so far, but should we reject them instead ?

Comment: @Jaco: They shouldn't be made by people who have less than 2000, and whose edits need to be reviewed as far as I understand...

Comment: Today I have noticed many of these edits in my review queue, in particular as I have been skipping reviews for this type of edit.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) is gone now, but [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple)'s still around and [currently discussed again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333833/321973). At least its description reads

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!! Apple is the company that manufactures Macs and iOS devices. Use tags more relevant to the OS and device/computer you're targeting.