# Should we approve suggested edits just removing [apple]?

Tags: discussion, tags, review-queues, suggested-edits

I see user [phatwrat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467396/phatwrat?tab=profile) suggesting lots of edits only removing [apple], and ignoring all other issues.
Here are a few edits he suggested:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8176745
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8176916

when I look at his [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467396/phatwrat?tab=reputation) I see lots of approved edit suggestions following that pattern.
I also see this tag has a notice ["recommended not to use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple).
He references [Followup to "Blacklist the [microsoft] and [apple] tags"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293754) where the consensus is to kill[apple] and [microsoft].

My question is should I approve suggestions which only remove [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) or [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd decline them if that's the only change being made. These updates are being made en masse with little or no thought. They aren't really improving anything, and they're needlessly bumping questions.  [Can I create a app that has images of Apple products?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928312/can-i-create-a-app-that-has-images-of-apple-products) should have just been closed, not retagged. It's a legal question, not a programming question.

Comment: Generally for single tag removal unless the tag clearly is a mistake, I decline the edit

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I was just trying to be helpful and didn't realize the edits would cause negative side-effects.  I will be more thorough on future edits and will work in smaller batches.  Thanks for your (plural) patience and mentoring.

Comment: @PhatWrat Thanks for taking notice and working to improve.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that he is removing tags recommended not to use, I think he is doing a cleanup.

But doing edits en masse is a bad thing, because it litters [this view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).

In a such situation the best what you can do if you change only a few question at once, and with the tag removal, you make other changes/fixes which seem needed (adding new tags, fix grammar/spelling, etc).

In your case I would approve the edit suggestion, but warned the editor for this in a comment.

Comment: He seems to have missed the occasional "thanks" which suggests a "@Phatwrat: please make sure to address as many problems as possible" may be warranted - or the advice not to clutter the Suggestions Review queue and let higher rep users take care of it. ..I think most of the questions he changed ought to be closed anyway ...

Comment: If those were good edits (1. on on-topic posts 2. Dealing with most/all issues) there would not be any issue at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator: ... true. So this is slightly disruptive behavior that ought to be stopped? I.e., the bumping-up cannot be helped, but the combo not-good-enough edits + clogging the Review queue is?

Comment: @Jongware, he also missed many other problems with the questions. I've left him a comment and someone else from chat has flagged for mod attention. Id think that a combination of insufficient edits and clogging the queue is bad.

Answer (score -1):

I think the bumping of questions isn't an issue. Potentially losing position in the list versus better (by some measure) content, the content wins for me.

Maybe there can be a grouping of similar edits where many edits only removing 1 tag can be condensed.

The idea of necro-ing a post really doesn't bother me at all. We should be focussed on better content, not avoiding an inconvenience.

Comment: There was a suggestion to have "minor edit" like on the Wikipedia (minor edit wouldn't bump). The SE doesn't want it.