# I want my (overcooked) [Apple] pie!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, blocklist-request

Let’s remove [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) once and for all!

But first let’s blacklist it, so we can edit it without fighting against users putting it into their questions.

(and remove [the documentation proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apple/commit)).

---

Quoth [the tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apple/info)

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!! Apple is the company that manufactures Macs and iOS devices. Use tags more relevant to the OS and device/computer you're targeting.

I listen very well to all-caps and exclamation points.

People have [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293754/followup-to-blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags)​ [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags)​ before, but it never seemed to materialize. ([microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) has been removed, though).

Comment: Sounds like a job for @burnaki

Comment: @pnuts according to shog, we aren't supposed to be editing the tag out of questions that don't need the tag, that can be done using a script which doesn't flood the front page. During a burnination you should be voting to close questions that are off-topic. How the deletion part is supposed to work is still unclear to me at this point.

Comment: @pnuts Then start your own [tag:burnination-request]s.

Comment: With regards to the mention of Burnaki made earlier, [this is StackApp that I started](http://stackapps.com/questions/7027/burnaki-tracking-progress-and-helping-burnination-efforts-on-stack-exchange) whose purpose is to track and monitor burnination efforts. The bot is not (and will not be) active in any other manner.

Comment: @pnuts you can be as cynical as you would like to be, but that doesn't help the situation at all. Yeah the world ain't perfect, but is complaining about its imperfections going to make it any better?

Comment: Given the sheer size of this tag (3,301 questions when I post this comment)   and the experience the SOCVR had with [godaddy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy) the [SOCVR room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) will **NOT** be heading this effort due to the impact it will have on both the site and the health/enthousiasm of our regulars. Feel free to use [the process guidance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags) but others have to organize the effort needed. If you need coaching, just ping us

Comment: I prefer to be blacklisted first, whenever or not we decide to bulldoze it, at least we can give better guidance meanwhile.

Comment: Why why this tag even created in the first place??

Comment: @VSG24 Looks like a user in the innocent days of meta-interspersed-with-main: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143374/call-151-what-did-it-do-on-the-apple (i.e. the [tag:Apple] ][)

Comment: Can't we just blacklist it, and then work through x questions a day?

Comment: @heather We need a moderator to do that, I think.

Comment: @JF, thanks for clarifying; didn't know about that. Can you flag this for moderator attention and explain?

Comment: there is also Documentation proposal for apple tag :)   http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apple/commit

Comment: Maybe we should also remove [lg tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lg) also then

Comment: @ThomasAyoub If you think it’s worthwhile, create your own [burninate request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion+burninate-request)

Comment: We should remove all company tags if there are any. [apple] , [lg] , etc.

Comment: @heather I already flagged to get [featured], as per [the burnination guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/5244995).

Comment: Yes, please finish [my](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1) [five year mission](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Five-year_mission) :)

Comment: Please blacklist the apple tag. Since early September I have been removing the apple tag from any new questions on a daily basis which is why the most recent question with the tag is from September 2nd. I didn't want to go back and edit the earlier questions to avoid them showing recent activity.

Comment: If we remove one company tag, we should remove all of them. And that's a huge project.

Comment: @Lundin How huge that would be?

Comment: @ManojKumar To begin with, we have the most likely suspects: Apple, Microsoft, Google, Adobe, Oracle etc etc. Then all hardware manufacturers: Intel, AMD, Motorola, Freescale, NXP, Microchip, Atmel etc etc. Then all the tool vendors. Then all popular sites. There must be thousands of company tags, splattered over millions of posts. To remove the company tags without vandalizing the post, you would have to edit each post and replace the company name with the relevant product from that company... which probably means lots and lots of manual edits.

Comment: Wow! Quite an explanation. But that also means we will have teamwork and lots of fun around here ;)

Comment: I'm for restricting the usage of this tag and others like it.  However, it's worth noting that [the tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/apple/info) for [tag:apple] contains a comprehensive guide to other Apple-related tags acceptable for use.  If we burninate the tag completely, we lose that page.  Is there any means of keeping that reference around?  It'd be great to have something more intuitive built-in to SE itself; a "did you mean" expansion function of sorts that shows related tags when you attempt to add a blacklisted tag.

Comment: Oh, that delicious smell of apple pie lured me into looking at this meta question. I would suggest we burninate [dough] along the way.

Comment: @macserv you could consider posting an answer here where you take the tagwiki content and conserve it the answer until is decided what to do with the tag.

Comment: @macserv if it's blacklisted, you can put that content on the blacklist message itself.

Comment: *Should we get rid of this rotten [Apple]?*

Comment: An [tag:apple] a day, keep this tag away! :D

Comment: @pnuts - I disagree with the relevance of some of the tags you name. Yes, Apple/Microsoft deletion makes sense. They are company names separate from the software name, while stack overflow is about software questions, meaning the questions asked are practically always being mislabeled (i.e. are really about iOS, Windows, etc.) But some of the company names you give are the name of the software too. Tagging them with those names would be appropriate if asking questions about that software. If Apple changed it's company name to "iOS" that wouldn't mean the iOS tag would suddenly be bad.

Comment: I'm for removal.  Unless we are going to start supporting produce in SO.

Comment: Please note that the burnination process [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag) includes the removal of a punny title when the [meta-tag:featured] tag is added.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Trogdor the burninator, not a bunch of software engineers.

Comment: @Undo What does [meta-tag:status-review] mean in this question? It doesn’t appear on the guidelines after [meta-tag:featured] is added and removed.

Comment: Moderators and CMs are discussing whether we can blacklist, bulk-remove, or both. Review was the best tag I could find to take it off the featured list.

Comment: Any updates on this request?

Comment: @FelixSFD No updates yet.

Comment: I was actually going to ask the same thing - it seems like there's community consensus that this ought to be done, and it's listed as "planned." Is there any progress on this?

Comment: @EJoshuaS waiting for the blacklist, but for that we need to have a message, and for that people needs to review questions. The thing stopping this is that we aren't doing anything. Reviewing the most egregious cases of off topic questions and crafting a message for those is a chore.

Comment: This question is discussed on another meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387516/what-is-the-etiquette-on-question-titles-once-a-burnination-is-completed

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Big thanks to everyone who pitched in.

[image: This tag has been burninated!]

Comment: Personally, I don't how burninating eg. the [tag:apple] & [tag:samsung] tags would help people with general programming problems that apply to multiple products of that company. When considering situations where a programming question may apply to eg. all apple operating systems or all samsung mobile devices, allowing only more specific tags would result in less exposure of the question and therefore a reduced likelihood of getting your question answered. How is that progress?! —— See also [**my answer here**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350753/1946501)

Comment: I think this is a case where folks try to distill these problems down into pithy names ("company tag") and then apply a blanket solution, @John; that strategy is fraught with danger. Apple (and Google, Microsoft...) are problematic because these companies each have multiple, distinct, *extremely popular* products - if I spend my days doing VBA, the overlap in my expertise with C# web apps and XBox dev is pretty slim, but they're all plausibly [tag:microsoft] questions *and there are thousands of each*. SAP, Sony, JetBrains, etc. do not have these same issues, at least not yet.

Comment: Why force tags to be as specific? Or to put it differently : what's wrong with general tags? The more general the tag, the greater the visibility of your question and therefore the more likely it is you'll be getting an answer for it! IMO the best way to get a good answer is to combine both general & specific tags.

Comment: @Shog9 Since you mentioned "SAP".. SAP has actually the same issue. Its product range is extremely wide nowadays: from backend solutions to CRM and even UI/UX with UI5 web components and Fiori design system. Now there seems to be a [consensus that 'sap' should be the next tag to be burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402154/5846045).

Comment: I'm sure Sony has more products than SAP, @Boghyon - and certainly did when I wrote that comment. However, most of them are not asked about on SO, and the ones that are asked about only occasionally. When that changes (for either Sony or SAP) then it is time for more specific tags.

Answer (score 28):

I've started [a chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141300/burnination-progress-for-the-apple-tag) to coordinate cleanup of questions tagged with [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple). The burnination bot, [Burnaki](http://stackapps.com/q/7027/43403)* is also tracking the tag to ensure accountability for questions with the tag that are closed or questions where the tag is removed.

## Progress

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:

- flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- cherry-pick questions with [Queen](http://stackapps.com/q/6910/43403);
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments.

Here are some easy links to get you started: [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple)

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapple%5D+closed%3Ano) 0
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapple%5D+closed%3Ayes) Zero
- <s>[No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapple%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) nil</s>
- [No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapple%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) Not a single one

[Review in the Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=apple)

[image: Burnination progress]

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority! If you have specific questions feel free to join the ["Burnination progress for the apple tag" chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141300/burnination-progress-for-the-apple-tag) or leave a comment under this post.

<sub>* for the moment, it has to run under "Guttenberg"'s account</sub>

---

<sub>I've copied major parts of this post from the [software-engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering) [burnination post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341979/4687348).</sub>

Comment: Very interesting statistics. ;)

Answer (score -39):

The vast majority of Apple-related programming spans all four OSes (macOS, iOS, watchOS, and tvOS). I call my common library of code "apple-common," because so much of it applies regardless of OS.

Would it make sense to introduce an [appleos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appleos) tag to cover Apple programming in general? What happens when someone tags their question with macOS but a potential answer-seeker searches for iOS?

Can SO's search be taught equivalences among tags (such that a search for [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) would turn up any of the four OSes)?

Or is the [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) tag actually useful?

Comment: These programming languages have names and thus should have their own tags, a user can tag his question with these. apple is just too vague.

Comment: Tags should represents what the question is about. Any question that covers all four of the Apple OSes isn't actually about either OS. It's about Swift or Objective-C or it's about Cocoa or Cocoa touch or about a specific framework. So no, introducing an appleOS tag makes no sense.

Comment: `Foundation.framework` tag? `Core Foundation` tag? `Darwin` tag? Those would encompass some of those common cases, and the others would operate similarly.