# What is the etiquette on question titles once a burnination is completed

Tags: discussion, title, burninate-system

Today I came across this edit: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/333833/revisions which had as edit description:

> Repunnified title

It changed the title from: "Should we burninate the [Apple] tag?" 
into: "I want my (overcooked) [Apple] pie!"

Whilst the former title wasn't descriptive of the question, seeing that this burnination was completed (and tagged as such), should we return to punny titles after burns were finished?

Or should we go for a title similar to what was done for the [Ebay] tag (and others): "The [ebay] tag has been burninated"?

Comment: Does it really matter?

Comment: to start with, repunnifying is officially legitimate because per [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/839601) punny titles are forbidden only during "featured" phase. As long as this phase over faq doesn't set any limitations anymore