# Is there [anylogic] in this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It appears that [anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anylogic) has a lot of non-programming questions to it. Not being an SME, what I've gathered thus far, is that it is a modelling software, in which you can script with Java. However, a lot of the questions on Stack Overflow use the visual, non-programming related, interface ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71689494/5211833), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71675942/5211833), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71668709/5211833) just from the last few questions asked) rather than the scripting one (e.g. [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71675753/5211833)).

Should an attempt be made to clean up this tag by removing the non-programming related questions in it?

NB: I'm *not* asking for burnination here, as the programming interface does appear to be on-topic.

Comment: If the tag is causing problematic questions I think we should do more than cleanup the questions, we should probably consider renaming it to something along the lines of `anylogic-api`.

Comment: What is *"[social norm dispersion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/anylogic/info)"*?

Comment: What would you define as "non-programming related questions"? Here is one from another forum "Which block is able to connect with multiple output and input before and after of Move by transporter block?" what is the difference from "How to fake declared services in Startup.cs during testing?"

Comment: I am curious about what the alternative suggestions for us as a community would be. Move to SuperUser or start our own Stack Exchange site? And if so how can we ensure our wealth of knowledge for programmers creating simulation models in AnyLogic is not lost. Can we export or migrate our existing questions? Apologies if this is deemed to require a separate meta discussion elsewhere. Would appreciate the feedback as we are looking for ways to handle this issue.

Comment: @Jaco-BenVosloo the outcome of the discussion here seems to be that AnyLogic is on-topic here and thus can stay.

Comment: Thank you @Adriaan. We appreciate your, and others, vigilant policing on Stack Overflow. We all benefit from keeping the site clean and useable. We will endeavor to do the same.

Answer (score 6):

For this discussion, I would like to go directly to the Stack Overflow help section on "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

The section clearly states:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
> who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
> questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
> generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Since we both agree that AnyLogic uses Java as a scripting language we can agree that it not only uses one of the most common programming languages for users to create code, but also the final simulation model is a Java program.

This we meet the Stack Overflow requirement of "software tools commonly used by programmers"

And since we have many many years of successfully answered questions (1.9k questions in total over about 10 years) We can say that we also adhere to the last point. "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

And since most of our questions contain "a bit of source code in them" we also adhere to the "best Stack Overflow questions" as dictated by the second sentence in the article.

So in the end we are "in the right place to ask" the questions we are asking.

Our biggest question to the OP would be the following:
Would "cleaning" the tag be helpful or harmful? And how does it align with the ethos and overall objective of Stack Overflow?

In my honest opinion, it would be not only harmful but a complete waste of our scarcest resources, time and attention.

We should also ask ourselves if this logic were to be applied to all other tags if this would be beneficial? Think about the hundreds of of thousands of [Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) questions that are not about programming but about the interface, or about some formula in a cell (Strickly not a programming activity)

If were to apply this logic to all other existing tags, I believe that Stack Overflow will be worse off.

So my final conclusion (and my ask as a passionate AnyLogic community member) is to not mess with this tag and remove years of value add.

Comment: Quite a few questions do not contain code, as I've demonstrated in the question, unless you count screenshots of the graphical interface as such. The ones with code are fine to stay IMO, the ones without are the problem. Comparing to other tags is rather moot, tags as big as [Apple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333833/5211833) have been dealt with. It's either on-topic or not. As to Excel: you can program in it, which is why it's on-topic here, other questions about it are suggested to migrate to [su], which might fit AnyLogic as well.

Comment: As to it being Java; there seem to be a lot of ways to use the program without ever actually seeing the Java code. Facebook's interface might be written in CSS/HTML (or whatever) but questions about how to use that interface aren't on-topic either. If a question actively uses Java to code, it's fine by me as stated in the OP, but clicking around in a GUI without touching code is what I'm concerned about.

Comment: I don't understand how comparing to other tags is moot? Surely what you are suggesting should be applied to all tags? Else it would not be consistent. 
But by your logic questions like these on Excel should also be closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates
(it contains zero code)

Can you please elaborate on why it has survived all these years?

I like your suggestion of moving to Super User it has merits, but in my opinion users there might then say we need to move to Stack Overflow due to the programming

Comment: *Can you please elaborate on why it has survived all these years?* Worst question we hear on Meta Stack Overflow. See [whataboutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism) for more about why comparing to other tags is irrelevant. There are thousands of tags on Stack Overflow, and only so many people who care enough to curate them. If you find questions you find to be off topic, by all means, flag or vote to close them. Just don't bring them here complaining that "my question got closed, what about this other one?"

Comment: @HereticMonkey we did not bring this discussion here at all. It was non-AnyLogic users accidentally coming across the tag and thinking "hey, this does look some non-programming stuff is going on". Without any knowledge about AnyLogic or the community. If you would like to not see this meta-discussion here, no one from the AnyLogic community will object. In fact, we'd be happy to be left alone :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment @HereticMonkey, I understand your concern about Whataboutism, so the answer to my question is then purely that no one has taken the time and effort to flag this specific question about Excel but that is in fact off-topic and ideally it should be flagged by a member of the community as soon as it is discovered? My concern is about the ramification of what is proposed in this OP. Can, and more importantly should, we really apply the proposed guideline to all tags and questions and answers? I would argue no we should not.

Comment: I am also concerned as to why no one is using the official guidelines provided by Stack Overflow, as I have done in this answer, to argue their case. Surely we must use the official guidelines to make a decision on what to do next and not be creating our own guidelines. If we do decide to only allow questions and answers about a programming IDE then we should specify that in the guidelines. Either way, whatever is decided please advise us on how to safe the wealth of knowledge we have before a final decision is made to remove old questions. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Almost all AnyLogic questions, even if they do not have any programming stated in the question itself, have a potential programming answer using either Java or the AnyLogic API. AnyLogic is 99% programming and questions about how to use the interface are extremely rare and not even worth addressing...

Now, your point might seem valid when you talk about visual interface... You might see screenshots that look very foreign to any non-AnyLogic user, and these screenshots look like an IDE that is not related to programming... but this is an argument from ignorance fallacy. If you don't understand AnyLogic and if AnyLogic doesn't look like any programming experience you have had before, it's probably not programming at all? That's nonsense, and it is proven by the fact that the very questions you showed as "problematic" are questions that actually require at least one line of Java programming:

**Example 1** makes use of the AnyLogic API as `roadNetworkDescriptor.size()` if this is not programming, what is it?

**Example 2** has explicit Java, so I don't even know why you put it as an example to support your case...  for instance `agent.timeEnterExamRoom=time();`

**Example 3** could be answered by using `enter.take(agent);` which is also programming and part of the AnyLogic API.

Now, is your problem having Java code placed in a screenshot, which is often done for AnyLogic questions? Or is there another problem? In AnyLogic it's sometimes annoying to write the code instead of showing screenshots, since there are so many sections in which Java code can be placed, and in a screenshot it looks more organized and easier to understand. Is there a rule in Stack Overflow that forbid us to do that? If there is, you should address that, and not the integrity of the tag.

I think you have a misconception on how AnyLogic works and what it represents and how things can be answered because you have a classical IDE/command line mindset. AnyLogic has visual aids, which is why you see screenshots with what might seem very strange for the typical programmer. But it's freaking programming.

The idea of using a different tag such as [anylogic-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anylogic-api) is an absolute tragedy, because beginner AnyLogic users, who are generally also beginners in java (and even advanced ones), have no idea about the difference between the AnyLogic API, and plain Java code, so you will just create unnecessary confusion. How can someone know if the solution requires the AnyLogic API or just plain Java? Also it has been RARELY the case, when the Java tag is used, that a non-AnyLogic user Java expert answers the question... probably less than 0.1% of the cases so using the Java tag along with the AnyLogic tag seems to be useless, even when the question is almost purely Java-based.

Now, if you really want to improve the tags then you can do what has been done with Excel, and then we can add to the AnyLogic tag something similar to the following information:

> Only for questions on Java programming with AnyLogic or questions that you think would require programming to be solved. You may combine the AnyLogic tag with Java, Python, and other programming related tags and questions if applicable.

then you can leave the tag alone, and reassess next year

Comment: Thank you for this well-written answer. Indeed after reading this, the tag seems a lot less off-topic than I initially thought. Your suggestion for the tag-wiki makes sense. As to code-as-image: for a visual editor you'll obviously need a screenshot showing how certain elements are linked. Text-based Java, however, [would be preferable as text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), as it is for any question with text-based code. Note that a question still must be *about* programming, not only have a programming answer in order to be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Adriaan any question that is *about* AnyLogic topics is *about* programming. This is just a GUI writing code for you. If a user asks about a rectangle being red, this is a coding question.

Comment: "have a potential programming answer using either JAVA or the AnyLogic API" the question itself should specify that. Up till now, most of the answers that are posted rarely if ever mention any api or code.

Comment: @Braiam I took 20 samples with answered AnyLogic questions, 14 had code, 6 didn't, 70% of the questions have code on this sample... so, in your definition, 70% is equal to "rarely if ever"... Sad to be discussing this topic not only to someone who barely knows what AnyLogic is, but also someone who wants SO BAD to rule against the AnyLogic tag, that he completely distorts reality and data... dishonest. 70% is not perfect, and there are questions that don't apply to the programming world, but that's why I suggested the tag-wiki change so that the tag is aligned with what stackoverflow requires

Comment: @Felipe go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anylogic?tab=Votes), do the same. I put more weight on what's considered a "good question/answer pair", the top voted answer of those "good" questions should also be "good" answers. They are not "good software development" answers as defined by the help center.

Comment: @Braiam same result approx... first 10 questions, 8 are programming questions, 2 aren't... the first question is the only one you checked that is not programming... unfortunately it has been the most useful

Comment: @Felipe yet, none has a programming answer as the top answer. How can a programming question be answered by non-programming answer?

Comment: @Braiam this is so easy.... the programming question can be "hey, why does my code doesn't work int i=0" and the non-programming answer would be "because you forgot to put a semicolon at the end of the statement"

Comment: @Felipe nah, that's not a non-programming answer, that's a programming one. A non-programming one is "use the gui", which all answers are (and yes, I don't consider the setting of env vars programming either).

Comment: @Braiam are you folks serious? Why do you try to limit people helping other people, without that disturbing anyone else? Why do you invest your valuable attention and time to this? This is really disheartening for us as a community

Answer (score 2):

I used Anylogic in my former job for several years.. and I still use another discrete events simulation tool daily.

Considering vison, functionalities and even UX, I see many similarities between any discrete events simulation tool (e.g. Anylogic, Tecnomatix) and Low Code platforms  (e.g Mendix)
If the latter are welcomed, why should not be the former?

Would you exclude any excel based discussion, because sometimes you find posts that cannot be solved with VBA only?

I would avoid hindering the great community built around any tool.

Comment: *"Would you exclude any excel based discussion, because sometimes you find posts that cannot be solved with VBA only?"* Absolutely. The vast majority of questions about Excel are off-topic and not welcome here. This is a programming Q&A site, not just a general place to ask questions. None of this seems on-topic to me. What does discrete event simulation have to do with software development? Who says that Mendix is on-topic? That doesn't look like a programming language to me.

Comment: @CodyGray and that's why I prefer excel-vba, rather than just excel. That argument wouldn't fly otherwise and nobody would bother to make it. It's easier and more effective to not give any impression you don't want, than having someone forming their wrong opinion based on a impression and convince them out of that.

Comment: "What does discrete event simulation have to do with software development?" I appreciate you may not know much about simulation but the father of all object-oriented programming languages was *literally* a discrete-event simulation tool (called Simula). Discrete-event simulation is, by its core nature, software development. Please stop this gate-keeping here :)

Comment: @Benjamin by that token, math is the father and mother and grandparent of all discrete science, so it should be on topic here. The topic on SO is limited to practical problems unique to software development. Abstract theory has no place here, unless there's a practical implementation.

Comment: "SO is limited to practical problems unique to software development" Which is *exactly*  what we are doing with #anylogic .

Answer (score 1):

AnyLogic is pure Java. It is *literally* a GUI on top of Eclipse. Everything you drag in visually is translated to code.

Therefore, every question is a programming question.

If a beginner SOF/AnyLogic user asks "how can I make this gray square red" and shares a screenshot of the GUI, we will tell him to use `mySquare.setFillColor(red)`

There is no reason to ban non-coding questions because that decision is always a subjective judgement. And it seems this is now raised by some people who have no idea about this tool at all.

EVERY question, no matter how "visual" or "non-programming" it may look to an outsider, is ALWAYS a coding question to us experienced users.

Answer (score -1):

> Programming is the implementation of logic to facilitate specified computing operations and functionality. It occurs in one or more languages, which differ by application, domain and programming model.[technopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/13128/programming)

Discarding AnyLogic because it uses a graphical model for generating the java code makes absolutely no sense. By this logic, one should only accept assembler questions on Stack Overflow.

Please can you elaborate on what the actual problem is with the tag and why you would want to limit its use? How does it negatively affect the working of the Stack Overflow community?

Comment: "By this logic, one should only accept assembler questions on stack-overflow." No, definitely not. Writing C# in VSCode, Java in Java SDK, Python in Spyder etc is all perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow, as is using AnyLogic as an IDE to write Java code. The uses where you don't see any code whatsoever are what this question is concerned with.

Comment: My point is the graphical blocks and their connections ARE the code. When the model compiles it converts everything to java which the java engine then converts to machine code for the OS to execute. AnyLogic is a Visual Programming Language or are you saying Stack Overflow is for text based programming languages only? What if you use some of the GUI tools in Visual Studio to generate your c# code?

Comment: I guess accessibility for blind people is not a hot topic for AnyLogic programmers then... ;).