# The [amazon] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag keeps popping up. It currently has 3744 questions tagged.

Why suggest to burninate?

- It is **ambiguous** -- is it referring to "Amazon Web Services (AWS)", or the "Amazon.com retail" site?
- It is the **name of a company**, such as "Microsoft", which doesn't narrow-down the scope of the question
- It **does not add meaning** to a Question

Frankly, the tag should probably be **blacklisted**, but that process starts with this burninate request.

Comment: I agree this is a bad tag, but I'm not quite sold on whether the site would be better off after putting a bunch of work in to remove it. Is it a magnet for bad questions?

Comment: @4castle:  The biggest problem I see with the tag's continued existence is that users conflate "amazon" as "Amazon Prime", "Alexa", "AWS", and other various services that Amazon happens to provide.  Eliminating it will remove at least one frame of ambiguity.

Comment: @Makoto Agreed, I don't see any case where a question would refer to Amazon as a whole.

Comment: Amazon is in the same ballpark as [the Microsoft and Apple tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293754/followup-to-blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags). Let's get rid of it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I assume that you mean wrt. this Meta. Why are you moving forward without actually following the [burnination process](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), which *explicitly states*: "questions **should *not* be edited to facilitate the bunination** until the process reaches step 4: Cleanup & BURNINATION"? (re conversation begun [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44409389/3773011))

Comment: Hasn't this tag been burned twice now?

Comment: @Braiam if it was I can't find it.  The "cut down the amazon" threads were about sorting out Amazon-Foo vs AWS-Foo tags.  Sorted by newest it goes back to '08, so it's about as a old as the site itself which argues against it having been burned before.

Comment: I spent half of my mod life just creating synonyms for the different amazon tags. :D

Comment: @BhargavRao I noticed. there's hardly a single page in the synonym list without your name on it :p

Comment: Is it sensible to remove the [tag:amazon] tag from all questions which *also* already have a tag for a more specific Amazon service? For example, questions with both [tag:amazon] and [tag:amazon-web-services]?

Comment: Would now be a good time to also remove the association of this tag with the AWS collective or would we just wait for it to be removed?

Comment: @apokryfos collective association is only controlled by the company. Nothing we can do about it

Comment: As a reminder, please don't remove the tag from [off-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157229/how-safe-is-amazon-web-services). Instead, vote to close them.

Comment: I mean yeah but like... who actually cared enough to bring this up xP

Comment: So I had a go at fixing some tags, and theres actually a few , not many, but a few, about literally using amazon book stores api. I have no idea what the appropriate tag for that would be except actually "amazon".

Comment: @Shayne It is probably `amazon-product-api`.

Answer (score 29):

[amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about scraping amazon.com itself should use [web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping), as well as relevant technologies
- Questions about selling, buying, or doing other user-level stuff on Amazon should be closed, not retagged. There's a solid chunk of non-programming questions in several categories as well.
- Questions about various services by amazon should use the respective specific tags, such as:

  - [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) for AWS
  - [amazon-dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-dynamodb) for questions about DynamoDB
  - For questions about the amazon selling partner API, as well as its subcomponents, such as the orders API, listings API, etc. (see [Amazon's docs](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/what-is-the-selling-partner-api) for the full list), use [amazon-selling-partner-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-selling-partner-api)
  - For questions about Amazon virtual machine, use [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services); other specific tags for specific offerings (such as [amazon-ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2)) may be applicable as well, if explicitly mentioned in the question
  - For questions about [Amazon's in-app purchase SDK](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-overview.html), use [amazon-in-app-purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-in-app-purchase)
  - ...

## Progress:

The [amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=amazon),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bamazon%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bamazon%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bamazon%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bamazon%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: What about questions closed as duplicate like this one [Programmatic access to Amazon Wishlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568209/programmatic-access-to-amazon-wishlist) (I'm sorry, I should asked before editing. I'm asking in case that more similar cases are found) This question originally had [tag:amazon] and [tag:web-scraping] it's from 2010 and the Amazon whish list have changed a lot...  It has two answers one that points to a GitHub repo of code that use PHP and JavaScript, the other answer uses Google Apps Script and Google Sheets formulas.

Comment: @Rubén just web-scraping looks fine to me

Comment: Why are we still accepting new answers with the amazon tag? Shouldn't it be blocked?

Comment: @m7913d Blacklisting tags is primarily reserved for tags that keep popping up after burnination. Also, due to overhead in the process (which mods don't have anything to do aside requesting it; it has to go through CMs, who have a sizable backlog of their own, who then escalate it to devs, who also have a backlog), the process of blacklisting, if we tried, would easily take a couple weeks in an optimistic scenario, or a month at least. As convenient as it would be to not have to deal with new questions, it just isn't feasible to blacklist the tag for a burnination that's this (relatively) small

Comment: Clean up of posts with the amazon tag but with content focused on scraping has been completed as recommended in the first point.

Comment: FYI, I just did a massive cleanup of AWS-related questions that had the `amazon` tag, replacing it with the `amazon-web-services` tag. I'm not familiar with the retail side of Amazon (eg `amazon-product-api`), so I left them alone. (Ironically, 6 years since making the Burninate request!)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that's a solid dent in the backlog. Thanks!