# Cleaning up [paypal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There's quite a few subtags under this and it's important to note that PayPal has some people who monitor only the main tags. Some synonyms would help people get answers (or at least show up for tags that are viewed by PayPal employees)

These are ambiguous and tend to be general PayPal questions (some lack the [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal) tag entirely)

- [paypalmerchantsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypalmerchantsdk) (28) -> [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal)
- [paypal-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-sdk) (84) -> [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal) (PayPal has multiple SDKs now, and they have their own tags like [paypal-rest-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-rest-sdk))
- [paypal-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-gateway) (14) -> [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal)
- [paypal-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-checkout) (5) -> [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal)
- [paypal-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-php) (17) -> [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal)
- [android-paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-paypal) (3) -> [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal)

Comment: No way in the unicorn this should happen! Paypal is a company, those tags are products. Haven't we learned from microsoft, apple, twittter, facebook tags anything!? [paypal] is the one that should be removed, not the products tags.

Comment: @Braiam Normally I'd agree with you but this isn't another [apple]. PayPal itself supports the tag (like [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6933189/paypal-brandon)) and the vast majority of questions are related to writing software that interacts with PayPal APIs. I also limited this list to places where the actual product isn't being tagged (i.e. [paypal-sdk] (there's 3 SDKs...) vs [paypal-rest-sdk]).

Comment: Meanwhile the `Amazon` tag is being discussed as too ambiguous... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345643/burninate-request-amazon-tag

Comment: @WilliamIsted, in that case, here is for [tag:Paypal]: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345880/burninate-request-paypal-tag

Comment: @WilliamIsted I have responded to the [amazon] comparison [in my answer to burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345889/2370483)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged the first two ([paypalmerchantsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypalmerchantsdk) and [paypal-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-sdk)) into [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal), so [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).
I disagree with [Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345870/366904) here (a debate we've had several times in the past) that there is ever a reason to have "sdk", "api", or any other such ornamentation in tags on Stack Overflow. Everyone knows we are here for programming questions, so that you are asking about the SDK or the API is pretty well implied. If it isn't, then you simply cannot be helped. There's no point in making our tags extra noisy when those who lack a clue still won't get it.

[paypal-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-checkout) no longer exists (not even as a synonym), so someone must have manually cleaned that up already. I don't see any compelling reason to retrospectively create a synonym here.

[Lundin already manually burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345865/366904) [android-paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-paypal), so there's nothing to do there. Again, I don't see any real point in creating a synonym. The tag only ever had 3–5 questions to its name in its heyday.

For [paypal-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-gateway), there were only a handful of questions with that tag, and all of them already had the [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal) tag, so I just merged and removed it from the system. Unless you feel strongly that it *needs* to continue to exist in the form of a synonym, removing it should be sufficient.

I did not do anything with [paypal-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-php). I'm not convinced that [paypal-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-php) should be merged directly into [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal). Are they really the same, or is there something different about the PHP bindings? I don't know enough about this to feel comfortable making an executive decision. I'll leave someone a bit more knowledgeable to do a manual cleanup.

Comment: Thanks Cody. [paypal-php] just seems like someone's attempt to combine [paypal] and [php] (and most of the questions overlap those two). There's nothing unique about implementing PayPal in PHP that it needs its own tag. PayPal's service acts as a gateway, so [paypal-gateway] is redundant. I'm more than happy to clean up the remaining tags

Comment: @Machavity Okay, well I don't think [paypal-php] needs to exist as a synonym. All of those questions already have the [paypal] tag, so a merge wouldn't do any good. Really, what several of them appear to need is the [php] tag. So yeah, feel free to clean those up. Everything with [paypal-gateway] already had the [paypal] tag, so I just did the merge anyway, which will effectively remove the tag from the system. Once you get [paypal-php] cleaned up, ping me so I can add a status tag to the question.

Comment: [paypal-php] is done. Can [status-complete]. Thanks again!

Comment: So, you disagree because it was me that proposed the solution? That seems to be a very poor judgment. There's more people that disagree with Machavity than with me.

Comment: Absolutely not. It has nothing to do with you. I just mean it's a debate that we've had before, and I haven't changed my mind. @Braiam

Comment: Well, I hope you do it and fast, or the actions you take would accelerate the decline of the quality of the site.

Comment: [tag:paypal-checkout] now has 11 questions.

Comment: @Bhargav Sigh. Thanks for the heads up. I took care of that. First tag merge in a long time for me! :-)

Answer (score 12):

This is the wrong solution for the wrong problem. Those tags are neither "ambiguous" nor "tend to be general PayPal questions". In fact, I would say that questions that have those tags are of higher quality than most of what you find on [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal). None of [paypalmerchantsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypalmerchantsdk)  [has score -1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpaypalmerchantsdk%5D%20is%3Aq%20score%3A..-1). Nor paypal-gateway, -checkout, -php (!!), etc.

The unanswered rate of most are near or lower than paypal tag, so there's no problem there either. Those tags are fine as they are. People who are interested in seeing all PayPal-related questions can just add `paypal*` to their favorites/filter and be done with it. Synonyms are for different spellings of the same thing last time I checked the thesaurus. Lets keep that definition here.

If the problem is "tend to be general PayPal questions" not related to programming, the solution is to make sure that all tags are specific to programming, like [paypal-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-api), [paypal-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-sdk), etc.

Comment: *"None of paypalmerchantskd has score -1."* This is not necessarily a proof for the quality of the question. This can also mean, that their voters are far less strict what "quality" is.

Comment: @Tom considering that most these questions also have [paypal], that's not an valid argument.

Comment: The problem is that 1. Not all of them are tagged the same way 2. There are more specific tags now that would 3. The word synonym, **as applied to SO** means that the tags make less sense than other tags. Using your strict definition, there should be virtually no synonyms on SO. PHP has 15 synonyms that are NOT different spellings of PHP. The idea is to make these ~150 questions correct and remove the poorer tags so people don't use them in the future.

Comment: @Machavity are those really a problem? Obviously, the tag for the sdk wouldn't be used for the api, and that's a good thing. Second, if you want to remove specific tag, start for tag-version tags, or language-library-function tags. Those are a waste of time. These tags represent a net positive for the answerers interested in only one aspect of paypal myriad of developing tools, like MS, Google, etc.

Comment: Using my strict definition or synonyms there would be indeed no synonyms because we use tags for unambiguously concrete terms, like product names, which usually don't have synonyms (gillette and razor blade, comes to mind of one of such cases), so I don't see where would be the problem: synonyms barely used because there's no need. BTW, where are the victims of the poorer tags? Stats don't support such argument, since those questions are equal or better than the main tag, wouldn't your action actually harm those that are better while not improving the others. How that work exactly?

Answer (score -14):

You could burninate most of these without much of a guilty conscience and without filing a formal burninate request.

I just burninated [android-paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-paypal).

EDIT

The core problem is that the tags have inconsistent naming and no tag wiki explaining when to use which tag.

Ideally I think there should be one tag per SDK (?), named consistently [paypay-sdk-xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypay-sdk-xxx) instead some random names that say nothing.

Then the global Paypal tag wiki points at the different SDK tags.

And then finally when this is in place [paypal-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-sdk) can get burninated.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to create the synonym to prevent future taggings. It's done now, tho

Comment: @Machavity Probably better to blacklist the tags then.