# Burninate request: [paypal] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

Burninate request: [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal) tag as unspecific to a product.

Similar: [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple), [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), [amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon), [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google), ...

---

*clarifications*

I was unaware it was a sponsored tag

Comment: +1 - I see what you did there...

Comment: A synonym request for many of the things you name was [posted a few days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345790/cleaning-up-paypal), to do exactly what you think to be ambiguous.

Comment: Eh... We'd allow it if it was a good idea (I've removed sponsored tags before; we'd just transfer the sponsorship to another tag / other tags). I'm not really convinced this one's necessary though; PayPal having multiple APIs is a lot closer to Android having multiple APIs than it is Microsoft having multiple products.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't care about tag sponsorship when deciding the burn/not burn state of a tag. They may just tell them the heads up in case something needs to change on the other party side.

Comment: @Shog9 that sounds like a task for the renametor? paypal -> paypal-api?

Comment: There are multiple PayPal APIs, @Braiam.

Comment: @Shog9 you are right. What is more interesting is that most of those services already have a tag in SO.

Comment: @Shog9 I hope you get the irony of tag ambiguity ☺

Comment: Hence my [tag:android] comparison.

Answer (score 9):

Since this was brought up under my retag question, let me flesh this out a bit more.

There are indeed some tags that describe a company as opposed to a product. [apple] and [microsoft] are prime examples. But where the analogy falls apart is that you aren't referencing **what you're programming**. [I made this case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/should-we-burninate-the-apple-tag?rq=1#comment408083_336921) (10k+ link) on one of the deleted answers for the [apple] burnination

> The problem with this thinking is that it's an optimism not borne out by how users actually use the tag. Apple makes products. People then ask questions about said products and not programming. iOS and OSX are places where you would write programs so they can have on-topic questions. But each is distinct from the other. Nobody says "I write programs in Apple", and if you said "I write programs for Apple" people would assume you were an employee.

PayPal is a company but (key distinction here) **it's also a payment service**. I call PayPal's API hundreds of times a day. I use PayPal services a great deal. So when a question is tagged [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal) you almost always know they're referring to the service. Furthermore, questions about using the PayPal website are off-topic and would be closed.

So let's play [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   Yes. Using this tag means you're referring to a PayPal service
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Using APIs and service calls are definitely on-topic
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Yes. It lets you know the user is trying to call a PayPal service. It also helps PayPal employees find and answer questions (which they actively do)
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Unlike [amazon], where its usage is ambiguous since Amazon runs lots of disparate services, I cannot think of any context where PayPal is used to refer to anything but a payment service

As to the suggestion of [paypal-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-api), my question is [which one](https://developer.paypal.com/reference/)? This isn't going to clarify anything for users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer on this, it is appreciated. Personally for the future, I'd like to see more disparity between tags. As when (if) PayPal expand to provide more services, the question then will be which "PayPal service?". This probably is ott categorisation on my part however. I'm not sure what the answer is, but as (if) the company expands the `PayPal` tag will be in a similar situation as the `Amazon` tag.