# Burninate Request [sony] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345889/2036035) to another burninate request, the criteria for burnination are as follows:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) could mean anything related to Sony and typically is being used to describe off topic problems.

- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

most of the time no, and when it is there are also other specific [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) tags that are actually on topic that are used as well.

- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, because the other tags already give the information that [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) is the manufacturer.

- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, hence why there are so many orthogonal tags relating to Sony, stating [sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony) doesn't give me a clue what you are actually talking about

[here is a link to the tagged questions with the sony tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony)

Comment: Markdown Pro Tip: you can use `[tag:sony]` to get a tag link in you question.  `[tag:tag_name]` will make a formatted tag which links to the tag `tag_name`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok thanks, apparently this is a duplicate any way though, stupid considering I couldn't find the other post because burninate was not in the title or description, even though it had sony tag...

Comment: tl;dr: if you're interested in retagging some of these, there's a lot of questions where [tag:sony] can be replaced with a more specific tag. Blowing away the sony tag doesn't help though, as it would simply leave a big pile of untagged questions and we'd need to go through & retag 'em anyway. See my answer on the other question - you can use search operators to identify questions in need of retagging, and usually the specific product involved. *Please avoid* removing the [tag:sony] tag in cases where it provides necessary context (sony-flavored android); those are confusing enough as-is.

Comment: @Shog9  Ok, is there a limit on the tag edits I can do? Right now there are a metric tonne of questions that have tags that both have [tag:sony-someproduct] and [tag:sony] in them, and in those situations the tag can just be removed.  Most of the [tag:sony] questions aren't even on topic, so can I just flag them or should I bother to remove the tag as well?

Comment: There's a limit to how many edits you can have waiting for review at a given time; once they're reviewed, you can keep going. Please try to make your edits "count" - focus removing redundant tags and adding more specific ones, don't ever remove a broad tag leaving only an even-more-broad tag (removing [sony] and leaving, say, [java] benefits no one).

Comment: @Shog9 I can't figure out how the edit queue works, is it 200 edits globally or per question, or per user? I edit pretty infrequently on other peoples posts, but its constantly greyed out and full for me.

Comment: It's 200 globally (which it is currently very close to), and 5 pending edits per-person.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. It's a part of the burninate-request cleanup project. There's 515 more posts to process (down from 700 when it was started). We've started to clean up from the edges.  :)