# Disabling notifications for a question (it's 10 years old)

Tags: support, feature-request, notifications

I have a question I asked 10 years ago, and I still get answers or comments periodically.
How can I disable notifications for a single question like this one?

PS: about answers and comments suggesting blocking or dissociating, no, I don't want any of those. I learned a lot from the answers and comments and so can others, and it is obviously still relevant to some people. It's just that I moved on, and it's a subject that's not interesting anymore for me to dig in further.

I know it's not that serious, and it's just a bubble indicator on the inbox icon, but still, choosing to unfollow a certain post is pretty standard nowadays.

Comment: Consider to flag the question with a custom moderator flag, ask him to lock the question.

Comment: Asking for dissociation would seem less severe than locking. Clearly there's still interest in the question.

Comment: What kinds of comments they are? Are they good quality?

Comment: [You get used to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function#comment92186675_934524). Well, it's not a bad idea, but it should be a feature request. Currently there is no such feature.

Comment: Thats a good question. I will suggest you request it as a feature and add `feature-request` tag.

Comment: The answer is you cannot. You need to ask a separate question now with the [meta-tag:feature-request], but be sure to search meta for similar requests before doing so.

Comment: Wow, kind of A clockwork orange?

Comment: I tremble when I think about Jon Skeet's notifications.

Comment: I decided to be a busybody and track down the question. Either somebody's adding offtopic comments to it periodically that are all wiped again or OP has another account. I would press "protect" if that would block comments.

Comment: So, judging by the answers, there is no way to block or unfollow a specific question. Wow, SO seems so quirky.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Neither locking the question nor disassociation are ideal solutions:

- If it gets locked, no new answers can be added, and the current ones cannot be updated, so as time passes it will become outdated. You might not care about that, but the people searching for the answer in the future might.
- If it is disassociated from your account, you will lose all the reputation and privileges that you have earned from the question.

The best solution would be if an "unfollow" option existed for the post, that would silence the notifications from the specific post, but unfortunately this option is currently not available.

Comment: There would need to be a visual indicator that a post's OP isn't getting notifications as well so that people don't waste time leaving comments requesting clarification or changes to the post.

Comment: @BSMP Sure, but if a post is so popular for one to unfollow it, someone else is likely to come along and address the request.

Comment: That's true but some questions only an OP would be able to address.

Comment: To call that the "best" solution requires that you consider only the personal comfort of the author of the post. From the perspective of site quality and maintaining the question, that is much less than ideal. A more ideal solution from that outlook would be more limits on who can post comments and answers in the first place (perhaps reputation based or copper tag badge or something of that nature).

Comment: @jpmc26 ok probably not the best, not sure what you propose, but at some point OP has done his part, other people must take over.

Comment: If the author no longer wishes to maintain the question, then disassociation is appropriate, if extreme. I suppose SE might want to consider some sort of expansion of community wikis that is equivalent in effect to disassociation, if they want to make it easier for users to do themselves.

Comment: Just add "unfollow", like on most fora. There are situations where comments and answers are no longer relevant.

Comment: I just got a new answer for the question `SQL - how to select an empty resultset` I asked 11 years ago, 2009, and I don't even remember why I did. The question has lots of correct answers, one of which was marked as accepted the same year, lots of comments and constructive debate, yet a new user decided another answer was needed.

Answer (score -20):

If you do not wish to receive notifications for a popular post, it means you're no longer maintaining it.
<sub>(if it's an unpopular post, then get it closed/merged/deleted)</sub>

#### An available solution: dissociation

Dissociate yourself from the post by flagging it explicitly for moderator attention.

With a dissociation, reputation changes from this post will be nullified and the author display name changed to "*anon*" (or similar neutral name). Example done here: [Burninate request: [paypal] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345880/burninate-request-paypal-tag)

This solution is a slow process: it may take many days as it requires a Stack Exchange employee intervention. Relevant discussion: [Please implement clause 7b of the CC-by-SA license](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288274/please-implement-clause-7b-of-the-cc-by-sa-license)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/209087) *"The original author [of a CW post] still receives notifications for substantial edits or comments on the post."* It is not clear if notifications for new answers are retained.

Comment: @Cœur: "*If you do not wish to receive notifications for a popular post, it means you're no longer maintaining it. Solution: dissociation*" That is an incredibly extreme solution to not wanting to be bothered by the random natterings of people who feel the need to fling their thoughts at you. Most comments on such questions are not "here's a problem that you should be aware of". Dissociation for solving this problem is like killing a fly with a stick of dynamite.

Comment: @Cœur: Both options cause unnecessary and pointless collateral damage. In the one case, you destroy the fly and everything around it. In the other case, you stop random natterings, but now it's not your post anymore, even though you are what made it what it is. Basically, I'm challenging your premise that "I want to stop natterings" is equal to "you're no longer maintaining it". These aren't the same thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas OK. But I still stick to it: no desire to receive notifications for a specific post is, in my opinion, equal to no desire to maintain this specific post.

Comment: @NicolBolas The site does not offer a way to distinguish between noisy and useful comments beyond flagging them after the fact.

Comment: @NicolBolas It may be an extreme solution, but it's the only one currently available.

Comment: @NicolBolas Extreme solution for extreme annoyance. If it's only occasional, you probably wouldn't be bothered enough by it to really warrant any action on SO's part. If it's not bad enough to warrant this, congrats on your popular question and welcome to normal functioning of SO. I agree with this answer; if you're not willing to deal with a few notifications, you're not willing to maintain the post and your name shouldn't be on it.