# A comment to my question is the best answer - should I accept another working solution proposed as answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, accepted-answer

Referring to [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635127/dynamic-variable-names-in-r-regressions/53637050#53637050), the answer provided by Roland in the comment is (to my needs) the best answer (including other comments and the other answers). Should I still accept MrFlick's answer (which works as well but was posted later and I find Roland's approach to use base-R-only preferable. In other words: If Roland had posted his comment as an answer I would have accepted it as the best answer.

Comment: You can ping Roland in a comment and ask him to convert his comment as an answer because it solved your question.

Comment: For this question, I think the combination of both answers are the correct course of action.  Ask the commenter to add an answer since their comment addressed your problem.  But if he/she doesn't respond or responds in a manner that suggests that they won't leave one, then you should feel free to do it yourself.  Just be sure to give credit to the commenter.

Comment: Side note, regarding "posted later", please don't consider that a factor of which answers should be accepted/upvoted.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't **have** to accept any answer. If other answers are OK-ish but not "perfect" in your mind, you can leave the question without an accepted answer.

In this case, I'd answer the commenter and ask him to publish his comment as a fully-fledged answer. You can also state that you'll accept this answer if his publishes it, as a form of encouragement for him to do so.

Comment: And if they don't, you can formulate the content into an answer yourself. If you feel guilty about gaining reputation from that answer, you can mark it as a Community Wiki. (I wouldn't feel guilty about earning the rep unless you used the comment almost verbatim, though, which is not a thing you should be doing anyway.)

Answer (score 16):

In such cases I am asking author (in comment) to write a "true" answer and if he replies with smth like "I'm too lazy today" then create "true" answer by myself.

Answer (score 14):

The logical option is to just post that comment as an answer. Remember, comments are not answers.

Comment: And one may eventually decide to publish it as a Community Wiki answer in such scenario.

Comment: that's a legit criticism - they might first respond to ask the commenter to put it in an answer, and then if they don't respond or act, write the answer themselves. In which case, CW is an option, but I'm hawkish on CW because it basically says "I don't want to own this content." I'd rather they work hard to present the answer well and get credit for it than not.

Comment: @Cœur: That's what I did when I found comment as answer or OP-edit-question as answer during value burninate.

Comment: @AaronHall the one to create a post which is made CW will still receive notifications: so it doesn't mean "_I don't want to own this content_". And despite it being my most downvoted post ever, I believe that the current correct answer to stop owning a content is **dissociation**: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375410/disabling-notifications-for-a-question-its-10-years-old/375419#375419

Comment: With a CW answer, you don't receive notifications of **votes** (including ***downvotes***), and that is the primary way that my content comes back to my attention, and leads me to continue to curate my content. With CW, I give my answers very little attention - I get no reward for giving them attention, and I get no notice that they need improving.

Comment: @Cœur CW is for a more aggressive collaborative editing. CW is not a short hand for not doing proper attribution. I can attribute a post to someone and still not mark my answer as CW.

Answer (score 2):

1. Prompt the person who wrote the comment to post it as an answer, so that you can accept it.
2. Give them sufficient time to respond (a couple of days).
3. If they don't respond or don't want to write an answer, then write an answer to your own question and later accept it.

You don't even have to acknowledge the source (although it might be appropriate). Anything posted as a comment rather than an answer is fair game to "plagiarize" without attribution.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, as much as that would be convenient, there doesn't seem to be anything in [the referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) to support the idea that comments don't require attribution. So I'm not comfortable endorsing the idea that it's okay to copy stuff from a comment without attribution. Other than that, I completely agree with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

When this has happened for my questions, I've copied the comment into an answer, but made the answer Community Wiki, so I can not gain reputation from upvotes to it.

Comment: Why community wiki? You did the effort of posting an answer where others wouldn't. It's their loss, if they don't have the time or energy to post a proper answer.