# How can I block comment notifications from a specific question?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-replies

Sometimes, despite my best efforts to explain things calmly and rationally, I end up in a comment exchange that gets a bit heated, and I realize that I need to disengage. The issue is that the other party will typically make at least one more comment after I signal my intent to disengage, which then sends me a notification. This is a) irritating and b) more tempting than I'd like to admit.

When I make what I intend to be my last comment on a question, is there any way I can request the system not to notify me of any further replies?

Comment: No, no such feature exists

Comment: Should I retag this as a `feature-request`, then?

Comment: Probably, though, a better argument for such a feature would be cases where an unrelated discussion is occurring on your post that you don't want to be notified of, or that you have a post that is a decade old but still routinely draws comments that you don't wish to be notified of, rather than I started/encouraged a discussion and am having trouble ending it

Comment: Before re-tagging please make sure to property re-write as FR... (while I'd love such functionality I'd personally not waste my time crafting FR as it is extremely unlikely to be implemented like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375410/disabling-notifications-for-a-question-its-10-years-old... I'd suggest giving up and close as dup)

Comment: Are you asking about new comments posted by others on a question or answer *where you're the author* (only deleting the post or having the post disassociated from your account works), on a post where you've just left comments (delete all your comments), and/or a post where you've performed some unilateral action like editing the post (only deletion of the post works)?

Comment: "on a post where you've just left comments (delete all your comments)" - This case is what I had in mind. Will that really work even if people @ me (I understand that it won't auto-complete, assuming they refresh the page, but still)?

Comment: @Makyen Those options all sound like things that would be worth documenting in one place, if they're not already.  Perhaps here?

Comment: "after I signal my intent to disengage" My recommendation is not to do this; if you want to disengage, do so. Even if you don’t say anything more than "I disengage now", for the other party that is still a notification that is a) irritating and b) tempting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming it's not your post, there are a few ways that I know of, but they all have downsides:

- Deleting all your comments on the post prevents autocomplete. In order to not be pinged manually you can't have certain other interactions (e.g no casting a binding close vote, no editing)
- Get a user with your same name to comment after you. There aren't any other Karl Knechtels but maybe you can work out something with the two Karl Knechts out there?
- Have a moderator lock the post. All locks prevent comments, but a comment lock would still allow everything but comments.
- Use a userscript. There was at least one to [ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/323179) but I don't think it works for inbox messages.
- Write with such finesse that nobody feels the need to ping you.

If it is your post, there's really only dissociation but I doubt support would issue a large amount of dissociations for you. I guess userscripts would still be an option though.

Comment: What are the downsides to the last one? I can't imagine any, and I haven't observed any in practice across all my years of putting it into practice. :-D

Comment: @CodyGray You have to control your emotions and your emotions suck D: