# Apple Tag? Why don't we use it?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to post a question with the [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) tag, but it says not to use it in the tag's description. Why is this?

Comment: As the description says, Apple is the company not the tech you are targeting. You'd want to use something more specific instead of a generic tag like Apple.

Comment: Ohhh... So THATS why

Comment: So it's just like using the `Microsoft` tag

Comment: Exactly right..

Comment: See ["Blacklist the microsoft and apple tags"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags) for context.

Comment: I *think* the down votes are because it's obvious to others why this is. But... thank you for not using a tag that says [DO NOT USE THIS TAG!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple)! :P

Comment: OK. I will keep that in mind... :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The apple tag covers every product that apple has which means it is an extremely broad tag and applying it to a question does nothing to narrow down what the question is. Is this a question about programming on mac? iOS? iPad? iPhone? The list of possibilities is massive and you are much better off using a much more specific tag.

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!! Apple is the company that manufactures Macs and iOS devices. Use tags more relevant to the OS and device/computer you're targeting.