# Pull the [plugins]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

## Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

[plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugins) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plugins/info):

> A plug-in (or plugin) is a set of software components that adds specific abilities to a larger software application. If supported, plug-ins enable customizing the functionality of an application.

This description doesn't give us any real reason why we should use the tag, only what a plugin is by its definition.

## Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

While a plugin pattern could be useful for the site, most of the questions are going to be either too broad or opinion based.

## Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

The only information this tag adds is that the question is about a problem with a plugin, this can in most questions also be made clear by the context of the other tags invoked.

## Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, because most people use this tag for the platform/language specific plugin, while in broad sense of the meaning it is still a plugin, there are significant differences between the implementations, and therefore you cannot be a [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugins) expert.

---

This tag should really be burninated because it is almost always misused when any kind of plugin is involved in the question, and therefore the tag should be replaced with more specific tags or removed altogether from questions.

Comment: Pull the [plugins]

Comment: For most of those topics there is already another tag that describes it, like [tag:wordpress-plugin] [tag:jquery-plugins] [tag:cordova-plugins] [tag:eclipse-plugin] [tag:webpack-plugin] [tag:vscode-extensions] [tag:jekyll-extensions] [tag:jenkins-plugins] [tag:maven-plugin] [tag:gradle-plugin] .... .

Comment: I'm kinda partial to [Glade plugins](https://www.glade.com/en/products/oils-and-gels/glade-plugins-scented-oil-warmer) myself

Comment: title suggestion: burninate my [plugins] baby

Comment: @Machavity did you say [glade](https://glade.gnome.org/)?

Comment: I was disagree with the whole question, until I read "you cannot be a plugins expert.". That's very true and the tag probably isn't useful in a practical way to include in a question, or to sort questions by.

Comment: If this tag is got rid of, can the tag description of what a plugin is, be added to the related x-plugin tags?  People do come on SO looking for basic information like "what is a plugin."  It seems a pity to lose that information.

Comment: Not all tags need to make sense on their own. Or would you want to kill `[compiler-errors]` as well? There are many tags that qualify a question in useful ways *if used with a scope-tightening tag*.

Comment: @SList SO is a site for enthusiast and professional programmers. A person who doesn't even know what a plugin is probably shouldn't be here in the first place.

Comment: @Raphael From [the official help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags): “meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.”

Comment: @HermannDöppes Yea.... I think the community moved past that years ago. Meta tags definitely have to be handled with care, though. Anyway, this here is not really a meta tag. `[plugins]` *does* describe the question content, not its context. `[beginner-question]` would be a meta tag. (I think that description from the help page is oversimplifying and not accurate at all.)

Comment: @Lundin and how do you think people will learn what things mean if information is not available?

Comment: @SList Like they have always done. Read books, take classes, try things yourself.

Comment: @Lundin SO is a legitimate source of information alongside the others that you cite, and it is really a pity that the "if you have to ask that question, you shouldn't be working here" attitude still persists.

Comment: @SList SO wasn't created for people learning how to be programmers, but for the programmers.

Comment: I don't think getting rid of the tag itself will remove future questions that would be off-topic. If anything, this (and other) tags should be added to a "watch list" which are almost guaranteed to be off-topic, or too broad to be worthwhile.

Comment: @SList http://stackoverflow.com/tour. "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers." As such, SO has a scope and a definition of what is on-topic. A plugin is not necessarily something programming related, questions about software in general is explicitly off-topic. Similarly, a question "what is programming?" is off-topic, because a person asking that question cannot possibly be a programmer.

Comment: @Lundin You are being disingenuous to support a very weak argument, because plugins may have other meanings, but they also have a particular programming meaning.  Also you have shifted the argument from my original point of saving this information in related topics, to arguing against closing the topic, which is irrelevant to what I said.  I think there is nothing more to reply to you.

Answer (score 19):

There's a few problems here

1. 18k+ questions. A while back, [we burninated the godaddy tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy). That was ~2000 questions (the largest successful burnination to date AFAIK), and we wound up locking the tag at the end, instead of retagging about 200 questions. It took well over a month of concerted effort, and the scope really took its toll, since there was inevitable controversy over some of the closed/deleted questions. This would be the largest burnination ever, and my bet is **it would take about a year to complete** (and I'm being optimistic there).
2. Some of the other plugin tags mentioned in comments are synonyms of base tags (like [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) is a synonym of [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress)). It actually doesn't make sense to go backwards in those places.
3. While [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugins) can't really stand on its own, it does qualify tags. The problem is trying to go purely with a hyphen tag solution (i.e. [jquery-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-plugins)) is you would have a **massive** bloat of tags. Plugins exist everywhere, and writing or working with them is an on-topic reason to use SO. Trying to make one for every tag under the sun doesn't make sense. I'd actually argue some of the hyphen tags should go away and make them use this generic.

The case for blacklisting here is weak at best. But I just don't see the need for a full blown burnination here.

Comment: Keep in mind that burninating *can* be a one-step process: CM agrees, pushes the button, tag gone. That it takes time in most cases is only caused by the clean-up needed. The fact that this does take time shouldn't influence if burninatig is required. If it does take major effort you can be sure it will never happen.

Comment: "That was ~2000 questions (the largest successful burnination to date AFAIK)" Actually, it was [microsoft] http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284167/792066

Comment: @Braiam Good to know

Comment: "The problem is trying to go purely with a hyphen tag solution" this is what I've been thinking for a while now, though it appears that this has been decided before on Meta?

Comment: @g00glen00b not necessarily. For example on [unix.se] we decided that, given the volume of questions, tag versions makes no sense. We could do this here: if the tag volume is so low on, say, eclipse, it makes no sense to have one tag for the program and another(s) for all the plugins.

Comment: @Braiam Who cleans and monitors this? Let's say that a new user adds another question with an [tag:eclipse-plugin] tag, will someone remove it from that question or blacklist that tag? And what happens if there are a lot more questions about eclipse plugins a year later, will you reinstate that tag? Will you apply it to previous questions as well?

Comment: @g00glen00b blacklist is a developer/CM only tool. Anyone can remove a tag from a question, via edits. So, "who cleans and monitors this?" anyone interested in doing so.

Comment: I agree: kill all `[x-plugin(s)]` tags and replace them with `[x] + [plugins]`. (Staffers can do such retaggings upon request.)

Comment: If only we knew some programmer who could write a program to remove tags automatically.

Comment: So, your position is “make [plugin] a meta tag”? Arent' those [forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)?

Comment: Meta tags are tags that describe the *nature* of a question, as opposed to the *content* of a question. The definition given on the help page is inadequate. An example of a meta tag is [beginner] or [homework]. Notice how those are different from [plugin], which would indeed describe the content of the question. It *could* be used as the only tag on the question, although granted it probably *shouldn't*, because that makes the question harder for experts to find, which is the primary purpose of the tag system. @hermann

Comment: @Lundin I find your lack of faith in Shog9... disturbing

Answer (score 2):

> While a plugin pattern could be useful for the site, most of the questions are going to be either too broad or opinion based.

I think plugin development is very on topic for this side and doesn't has to be too broad or opinion based. These ones doesn't look too broad to me. [Design Pattern for implementing plugins in your application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177140/design-pattern-for-implementing-plugins-in-your-application) or [How to create a pluginable Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449/how-to-create-a-pluginable-java-program)

There are lots of software packages that enable different kinds of modifications. Sometimes you will actually modify the core product and sometimes you will only write a plugin. On example is [liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay) where there seems to be no [liferay-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay-plugins) (yet). You could create a tag for everyone of those, but I'd assume that generates much more rarely used tags and some really misleading ones.

Misleading ones could be [java-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-plugins) or [.net-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-plugins). The name would suggest you are writing a plugin for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) however you probably want to build your own product with api support. This one probably doesn't even have a known name yet and would disqualify for its own tag.

Looking at the tag even 380 people seem to find it so useful that they follow it.

I would rather keep it than creating an even larger mess.

Comment: I have yet seen someone that writes plugins that call themselves a plugins expert... if anything they say "I write plugins for X".

Answer (score 1):

You know what this burnination request lacks? Numbers, everyone loves numbers. So here numbers:

There are at least 10 users with score +10 in the [all time top answerers of the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plugins/topusers). The most upvoted posts of most of them seems to be one of the two:

- I want to do something with the/have a question about the plugin of X, with X being either maven, eclipse, wordpress, jquery, vim, etc.
- I'm looking for a plugin that does abc of X

Grails questions seems to be the only one tag that doesn't fit the above categories, most of them being in the form of "dependency hell" kind of issue. While the most recent ones perfectly fit above categories.

567 questions with the tag are closed, but I found many of the "looking for a plugin" that are not that needs closure.

There is [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/225883/question-stats-by-tag), but no conclusion can be drawn for it other that the average score and views is quite high:

```
TagName N     median_views avg_score closed_rate avg_answers accepted_rate answer_rate median_tta 
------- ----- ------------ --------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ----------- ---------- 
plugins 18068 262          1.6       3           1.3         46.1          82.3        100
```

Which we have to remember that doesn't includes deleted posts.