# Burninate request: [Luciad] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I came across a tag for a company whose products I've worked with in the past: [luciad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luciad). They make GIS software. Coincidentally, it was only added a few days ago.

All current usages (only 9) were added to existing questions by a single user. As it happens, most of the questions are very broad. None of them actually refer to the company or any of their products in the question. One includes the company name in a comment, another incidentally refers to their repository, though it's not an important aspect of the question.

Upon checking his LinkedIn profile (which I won't link to but it's easy to find), I can see that he's an employee of Luciad.

Can we ditch this tag? I suspect it has the *potential* to be useful - if only to a niche audience - but there are, as far as I can see, currently zero questions it applies to.

Comment: only 9 questions.... I normally burn that without asking meta... *ssssh ssssh*, close vote (if you need help to review pass cv-pls in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)), edit to remove where question is ok and internet in the end will be a better place.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Haha, I would happily but I didn't want to get into a war of untagging and retagging. I figured if there was a more public record of my reservations, it might come across less passive-aggressive.

Comment: Then the best thing you can do is to ping the user that is editing so he/she can contribute to this meta and maybe state why the tag is important. (note only 2 questions seems still to be open)

Comment: @PetterFriberg Alright, I will. And yes, Bhargav just closed a bunch. Most were open.

Comment: @Michael You were right to bring this one to Meta. But I really want to hear from this guy as to why he did this. It's not obvious at all.

Comment: We should be [luciad] about this.

Comment: Wow, it just comes off as blatant advertisement. Most of those questions should be closed, editor is just taking advantage of the fact that the ops picked a bunch of library tags for them to tack on one more. And the ones that aren't off topic don't actually seem to have anything directly to do with the product.

Comment: @Machavity : See my answer below...

Comment: The tag is no longer applied to any questions.  It will vanish within 24 hours when unused tags are cleaned up.

Answer (score 34):

Luciad is a company, not a product. We don't want tags for companies. For example, take a look at [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags) to blacklist the tags for Microsoft and Apple.

However, LuciadLightspeed, LuciadFusion, and LuciadRIA (as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350283/1476885)) are *products* and so, are perfectly fine to be used as tags to help developers to find questions of *real* problems to answer.

I vote to burninate the [luciad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luciad) tag and create (if there is a **real** need for this) the product tags: [luciad-lightspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luciad-lightspeed), [luciad-fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luciad-fusion) and [luciad-ria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luciad-ria).

Comment: I agree with this, under the provision that tags should be created based on the content of the *question* rather than products referenced in one or more *answers*.

Comment: The [tag:ibm] tag is being removed because it is a company tag and not really useful on its own, like the Microsoft and Apple tags.  Removing the [tag:ibm] tag is a low activity level effort I sometimes see in the suggested edits queue.

Answer (score 7):

I say we let it die.

Given [only two of the 9 questions in the tag are still open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luciad) and the remaining two have been edited by the tag creator

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43884932/revisions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27414282/revisions

I don't see any reason to keep it. Any valid arguments the tag creator has of making it are lost in the fact there's no on topic questions ([maybe one from 2014!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414282/how-to-convert-webp-to-png-or-jpg-using-java-in-windows)) on the entire site that are relevant to the tag.

If the rate of questions in the potential tag increases from one 3 years ago naturally grows, perhaps a tag could be considered then.

n.b. I'm not going to presume the tag creator's intentions.

Answer (score -15):

[LUCIAD](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/luciad) is a company that provides software tools for rapid application development of advanced [geospatial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geospatial_analysis) software solutions, mainly focusing on the Aviation, Defense and Security markets. LUCIAD's solutions include [LuciadLightspeed](http://www.luciad.com/solutions/luciadlightspeed) (a Java framework), [LuciadFusion](http://www.luciad.com/solutions/luciadfusion) (a geoserver), and [LuciadRIA](http://www.luciad.com/solutions/luciadria) (a JavaScript framework).

I joined the company two weeks ago and was surprised to find out there was barely any mention of Luciad on StackOverflow: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951176/how-to-draw-a-map-from-images/2951242#2951242), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653409/which-mercurial-plugin-should-i-use-for-intellij/3463055#3463055) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414282/how-to-convert-webp-to-png-or-jpg-using-java-in-windows) were the only SO posts explicitly mentioning Luciad.

I created the [luciad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luciad) tag to add to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414282/how-to-convert-webp-to-png-or-jpg-using-java-in-windows) (which references [this Luciad BitBucket library](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio)), and also added it to a few other questions where a helpful answer would be a reference to a Luciad solution.

While I would agree that the [luciad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luciad) tag would be useful only for a niche audience, this niche audience is still an audience of developers. Questions involving coding for eg. LuciadLightspeed or LuciadRIA would be totally on-topic on SO, and without a suitable tag it would be pretty much impossible for anyone to get a proper answer.

Comment: *"questions where a helpful answer would be a reference to a Luciad solution"* --  not exactly the same as "questions about Luciad", which is where the tag would be appropriate.

Comment: @PaulRoub : So eg. the [tag:javascript] tag shouldn't be used when JavaScript is mentioned only in one of more good answers to a question? That's new information for me... and seems like bad UX to me... In that case, however, that still leaves us with [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414282/how-to-convert-webp-to-png-or-jpg-using-java-in-windows) where the [tag:luciad] tag would be appropriate...

Comment: @JohnSlegers Tags are about questions, not their answers.

Comment: @DamianYerrick : As I said, that's new info for me... I'm pretty sure I've seen people add tags in reference to one of more answers as well (which I believe is better for UX), but I guess that's not what the SO guidelines prescribe. Which begs the question : what ARE the current guidelines for tags, and where can I find them?

Comment: Guidelines are in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).  Note the first line (emphasis mine): *A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the **question**.*

Comment: @BJMyers : That's pretty vague. More precisely, it doesn't mention whether or not "the topic of the question" includes the content of one or more good questions for that question. Either way, I guess I've learnt today that it doesn't...

Comment: Does a generic "company-wide" tag make sense, regardless? There's an ongoing effort to [burninate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333833) the [tag:apple] tag, for example. Why not specific tags per-product or -tool?

Comment: Making a [tag:luciad-lightspeed] tag would be okay if the question was about a programming issue related to this framework for example.

Comment: @PaulRoub : I'd say it depends on the amount of questions whether to have one tag for all products of a company or one tag per product. Considering there's currently just one question referencing an obscure Luciad library (not even a Luciad product), it seems to make more sense to me to have a generic [tag:luciad] tag than a tag specific for that library. As that tag could be used in reference to any Luciad library or product, it would be more useful in the future.

Comment: @JohnSlegers Nah, company tags are frowned upon by the community. Most have been burnt or are currently being so. You can find such burnination topics all over Meta.

Comment: @Kyll : I didn't know that... nor do I think that's a good idea... but that's just me, I guess. Anyway, it looks like I learnt something new today about SO :-)

Comment: @JohnSlegers you've been here a while. I can see you may well have had good intentions.

Comment: I don't understand why you added the luciad tag to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180793/gis-for-the-web) in which the OP says he can only run open source GIS tools. Would that help the OP get better answers?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : I do believe that having tags to solutions that aren't open source is still better than having only the [tag:gis] tag (because it attracts more GIS experts). Having said that, adding eg. the [tag:geomajas] instead would have made more sense. I edited the question again to relfect that.

Comment: @JohnSlegers Thanks for engaging in a civil discussion. Regarding your last paragraph I think you're completely right. When I was working with Lightspeed, I would have loved that. Unfortunately the relatively private nature of your documentation makes it difficult. I also don't think it fits with Luciad's business model (charging for support) so it's hard to see the company backing it too strongly. Some kind of knowledgebase for support questions would be great, though. Luciad make cool products, I hope you enjoy your time there.