# Finally we migrated from [atlassian]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

I just found the [atlassian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag on a question about [confluence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confluence).

I see about as much in a tag for the Atlassian company as I do for, say, [the `[apple]` or `[microsoft]` tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284167/215552).

From a brief glance at the list of 936 questions, the tag is almost always used with a corresponding Atlassian product (The abovementioned [confluence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confluence) and [jira](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira) being the most popular, along with [bamboo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bamboo) and [bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket) and others).

To the Four Questions:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   It does not describe the contents. It describes the corporate owner of the trademarks of the products being discussed in the contents. It's ambiguous which of the products the corporation produces is being discussed.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   The products of the company are certainly "commonly used by programmers", so asking about them is on-topic. However, asking about the company itself is not.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   I suppose, if you squint, it limits the scope of the question from the entire universe of software development tools to those published by Atlassian. But I think that's a stretch too far.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No. I've seen it used to mean ["a range of products published by Atlassian"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44461504/215552), ["The Altassian namespace"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44155715/215552), but mostly it's used as a companion to one of their product names.

I would love to see some discussion about removing this tag.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you obviously didn't sit down and went over those 877 questions to see if the questions should be edited/closed/re-tagged. Before a tag is burned, its questions needs to be cleaned up. I admit that it is a task not many seem to be eager to take on. On the other hand, we do have plenty of users who like to propose such requests and voters to vote on them.

Comment: @rene There is [a process for burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/215552), and I believe the next step is a moderator should add the `featured` tag... I didn't want to go ahead and start removing tags without following that process. If you have some advice on how to get this moving, it would be helpful to provide that.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sure, you might want to hop into SOCVR and ask which [post Vadim wanted to do](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=40429758#40429758) to prevent that multiple flags go out for a burnination. But in general flagging for a mod would be the thing to do, although it is still the mods call to determine the priority.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +54/-1. A1 (Saying Yes): +32/0

Comment: As this was started this on a Sunday, we will be leaving this [featured] for 48+ hrs, instead of the usual 36+ hours. (yes, [approval] broke my calculations as it took 1hr to burn the tag, rather than 1 day).

Comment: The [\[atlassian\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag looks like a **meta-tag** and can be burninated.

Comment: It seems obvious to me that those questions are offtopic here and should be either 1) in their support channels or 2) on [webapps.SE].

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +141/-4. A1 (Saying Yes): +104/-1/ A2 (Saying Yes): +16/0. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: I'm trying a small experiment here with the [featured] tag. Given that it has ~1000 questions, and that we have a election going on, being featured on the community bulletin might help us find more users at the start. I will unfeature in a few hours.

Comment: Note, atlassian products have many common in them: all of them are large Java apps, configured similarly - and all of them are trashpile (for example, Atlassian somehow won't understand that working directories and code binaries should be separated). However, I think these similarities are not enough to have a tag for them (overwhelming majority of atlassian problems aren't even about programming but sysadm/devops things).

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "**at last** we migrated from [atlassian]"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[atlassian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

This tag describes a company. While it can often be removed without replacing it with another tag, if the question is about a specific Atlassian API (or product), then the question should have the appropriate tag for that API (or product). If the question already has such a tag, then just remove the [atlassian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag.

There are several tags available for Atlassian REST APIs (or products). The following are some of those for the various REST APIs provided by Atlassin for their products.

- [jira-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-api)
- [confluence-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confluence-rest-api)
- [bitbucket-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket-api)

and so on. Likewise there are several tags available for Atlassian products:

- [atlassian-sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree)
- [bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket) or [bitbucket-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket-server)
- [atlassian-crowd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-crowd)
- [atlassian-fisheye](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-fisheye)

etc.

There are also questions regarding the Atlassian User Interface, which is used across their products and includes some JavaScript libraries. Use [atlassian-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-ui) for those.

## Progress:

The [atlassian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=atlassian),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Batlassian%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Batlassian%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Batlassian%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Batlassian%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188947)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=351480)

[image: burnination progress chart]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [atlassian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [atlassian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag —just flag/vote to close the question.

#### [Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009)

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [atlassian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 101):

I agree. It's not useful as the sole tag on something, and if you've already tagged it with the specific product you're asking about, this tag adds nothing useful.

The good news here is that, glancing at the questions, it doesn't seem like it's drawing a huge number of low-quality or off-topic questions, which should make it easier to clean up.

The main work will be going through all of the questions to identify the bad ones. After that, we could probably just have a few people filter on that tag in the close queue.

I say we go for it.

Comment: I agree. The only reason I'd tolerate such a tag is if there atlassian employees watching it.

Answer (score 19):

I support the burnination.

I checked the list of questions. It seems like a significant portion of them are off topic, which include questions that ask just to use the different web based applications. These should probably be closed as "Off topic -> General computing".

Similarly some of the questions tagged [jira](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira), [confluence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confluence), etc are mostly about using the web app rather than the programming using the APIs. Therefore the tag needs to be cleaned thoroughly. [hipchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hipchat) seems quite clean though.

There are also the following REST API tags available for the different REST APIs  that are provided by Atlassin for their products.

- [jira-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-api)
- [confluence-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confluence-rest-api)
- [bitbucket-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket-api)

and so on. Therefore it is very clear that there are lots of more specific tags already available which can be used in place of the [atlassian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag.

Comment: Doesn't Jira fall under tools commonly used by programmers, though?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I told "some of the questions are off-topic"... :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were implying that the Jira questions about using the web app are off-topic. (In my opinion, they're probably not general computing questions).

Comment: [tag:sourcetree] can probably be replaced with [tag:atlassian-sourcetree] wherever the former exists, too.

Comment: [jira] is 26% answered last month, [confluence] is 33%, [bamboo] is 17%. But [atlassian] is 100%. That's kinda awkward, hopefully it is just a sample size problem. I can't help feeling sorry for the people that bought a product from this company, maybe it is not such a good idea to obfuscate that detail. There is one user that is still active that really knows, it is mdoar. He needs to be consulted about this.  I pinged him, but he isn't around often enough to be sure he sees it.  Fingers crossed.

Comment: Thanks, we need more experts looking at these issues.

Comment: I don't see much use for the tag "atlassian" in these questions. I check the questions most days, but don't answer so many these days due to low volume. Feel free to ping me on my email address mdoar and pobox.com