# Rename [chef] to [chef-infra]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Chef has been [the name of the company](https://blog.chef.io/chef-the-company-formerly-known-as-opscode/) since 2013, and they finally changed the name of their "classic" devops system to [Chef Infra](https://docs.chef.io/chef_overview/) to help avoid confusion.

As such, we should rename [chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef) to [chef-infra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef-infra) to help this [avoid the same fate as other company tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags)

Comment: Have you confirmed that all of the questions currently tagged [[tag:chef]] are actually about Chef Infra?

Comment: @CodyGray While auditing all 6.2k questions is impractical, I did a cursory retag of the handful that were obviously using [chef] as a company tag. The Chef Infra rename is fairly recent (sometime in 2019) so there shouldn't be a lot (if any) which still need it. For instance [Chef Solo](https://docs.chef.io/chef_solo/) (which overlaps heavily with the [chef] tag) is a subset of Infra, so there's no retag needed there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the popularity of infrared cooking among contemporary chefs (wait, or did I misunderstand some of the details? ah well...), I think this is a clearly appropriate suggestion. As such, I've merged the tags, and made [chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef) a synonym of the new "master" tag, [chef-infra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef-infra).

There are [some tag synonyms proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chef-infra/synonyms), but I don't have the expertise to say whether any of those are appropriate. I'm uncomfortable with [cookbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cookbook) being a synonym, because that's a pretty generic term in software development.