# Rename [airbnb] to [airbnb-js-styleguide]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The [airbnb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airbnb) tag is specifically about their JS style guide, based on the tag wiki excerpt:

> For questions about complying with one of Airbnb's JavaScript style guides (located on GitHub). [...]

However, because the name is just the name of the company, people have historically used it for all kinds of things, even questions like "*How do I make something in my own app/site behave the way Airbnb's app/site does?*" Additionally, Airbnb as an organization is the author/creator/maintainer of a ton of products used by programmers:

- React Dates
- React Native Maps
- Apache Airflow
- Apache Superset
- Lottie
- DeepLinkDispatch
- Style guides for

  - JavaScript
  - Swift
  - Ruby
- An eslint config file
- TS Migrate tool
- Epoxy

And [many, many more](https://github.com/orgs/airbnb/repositories).

Luckily, pretty much all of these things have specific tags already, at least where there are questions about it. I believe I've finished correcting the tags on the couple hundred or so questions that misused [airbnb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airbnb), but the one that is still lacking (which most or all of the remaining questions are about) is a tag for their JS style guide.

Can a moderator please rename [airbnb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airbnb) to [airbnb-js-styleguide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airbnb-js-styleguide) or something similar, so I can avoid retagging the remaining three dozen or so questions and submitting a new tag wiki/wiki excerpt suggestion? This would also in effect "burninate" [airbnb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airbnb) as a vendor/meta tag itself.

Comment: I suggest making it more prominent in your question that you've already been through and retagged the questions which were misusing the tag - I went to look to see how badly the tag was being misused and figured there wasn't really a problem, until I saw further down your post that this is because you already went on a retagging spree. If you remember how many questions were misusing the tag, that would also be useful information.

Comment: @kaya3 I don't recall, but it was in the very low hundreds... 300 total maybe? That aside, the size of the tag is not particularly relevant when a tag needs to be renamed/clarified. Small tags are tags too, and the same clarity rules apply to them. I will clarify the wording a bit, though.

Comment: I meant more because if it's 300 questions misusing the tag compared to 30 using it correctly, then that makes a more urgent case for renaming it.

Comment: Would [airbnb-styleguide] be acceptable? Cramming "js" in the middle seems awkward

Comment: @Machavity No, because they have multiple different style guides (for different languages). Unless you think it's OK that [airbnb-styleguide] covers JS, Swift, Ruby, and more, in which case sure. It would be kind of like [sql] or [vba] then: you'd need to be prompted to enter the language you're using as a tag, too.

Comment: Fair enough. But why isn't a language tag sufficient for that? Do we need more tags like [airbnb-swift-styleguide], etc?

Comment: @Machavity I don't see any existing questions for the other ones currently. I don't have a preference regarding the requirement of adding a language tag and just going with [airbnb-styleguide] other than I feel like that requires a CM. But if mods can add tag warnings/requirements like that then sure I say go for it (and we can adjust the tag wiki excerpt to reference the various languages).

Comment: I went ahead and renamed as requested. Didn't have any compelling reason to pick the other option, just making sure on that front

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with this. We have a long history of removing company name tags. For example: [Blacklist the [microsoft] and [apple] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags)

In general, the [community consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful) appears to be that vendor name tags generally do not serve the site well.

Given that people (especially new users) tend not to actually read tag usage guidance, the fact that the usage guidance states the correct usage will not deter people from misusing it.

That being said, we should rename this tag as described in the question.